# sub() missing 1 required positional argument: ’string’

Tags: python, regex

I wrote such a regex with re.verbose

```
#+begin_src ipython :session flask :results output
import re

def clearup(path):
    fp = open(path, 'r+')
    text = fp.read()
    text = re.sub(r'''.*PROPERTIES:.*\n
                      (?:.*\n)* # multiple lines in the middle
                      .*:END: ''',text, flags=re.VERBOSE)
    fp.seek(0)
    fp.write(text)
    fp.close()

clearup("01.foreword.org")
#+end_src
```

Run it but report error:

```
 TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: ’string’
```

What's the problem since there are no arguments missing?

Comment: ...why is this getting upvotes? What makes this a good question?

Comment: _"What's the problem since there are no arguments missing?"_ - there is an argument missing. Did you read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sub takes three (excluding flags) variables. The first is the regex pattern. The second is the replacement regex. The third is the string to sub from. I think that's the error your getting as you don't seem to have a replacement pattern, but just the text.

Comment: In other words, "What's the problem since there are no arguments missing?`"—there _are_ arguments missing. Read [the documentation for the code you're trying to run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) before saying there are no arguments missing.

Answer (score 3):

From python document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

quite a lot of arguments, and together with re.VERBOSE, it is so confusing, and the position of the arguments is error-prone.

So I would suggest separating defining pattern and .sub move in to two lines:

```
pt = re.compile(pattern, flags = re.VERBOSE)
text = pt.sub(repl, string)
```

which is more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still confused about this or if anyone else comes here to read this. The author of the post was probably trying to call the sub function on the created Regex not on re.
When you do that, you only need to give 2 args to sub

i.e

```
myRegex = re.compile(.... something.....)
myRegex.sub( <regex pattern with which to replace>, <string that has to be subbed>)
```